# Checking radio-button status with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I made a form for an event. When I click the first radio button, then submit. The warning message disappears, however, if I click the second radio button, the warning does not. My question is the `some` function not suitable for this case? How do I revise it? What kind of case do we use `some` function? Thank you!

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.apply__form');

function createWarning(node) {
  // if there is no warning msg, then create one
  if (!node.querySelectorAll('.warning__style').length) {
    const warning__msg = document.createElement('p');
    warning__msg.innerHTML = 'Please fill in';
    warning__msg.classList.add('warning__style');
    node.appendChild(warning__msg);
  }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let result = [];

  // Check the required answer for name, phone, email, resource
  const reqAns = document.querySelectorAll('.required .answer');
  const reqAnsArray = [...reqAns];
  reqAnsArray.map(element => {
    if (element.value === "") {
      createWarning(element.parentElement);
    }

    if (element.value && element.parentElement.querySelectorAll('.warning__style').length) {
      element.parentElement.lastChild.classList.add('warning__disappear')
    }
    result.push(element.value)
  })


  // Check the required answer for the type of applying event
  const reqChoice = document.querySelectorAll('.required input[type=radio]');
  const reqChoiceArray = [...reqChoice];
  reqChoiceArray.some(element => {
    if (!element.checked) {
      createWarning(element.parentElement.parentElement);
    }
    if (element.checked && element.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll('.warning__style').length) {
      element.parentElement.parentElement.lastChild.classList.add('warning__disappear')
    }
  })

})
```

```css
body, html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background:#f0f0f0;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.apply__form {
  border-top: 8px solid #f00;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 645px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 50px;
}

.form__title {
  font: normal normal bold 1.8rem "Microsoft JhengHei";
}

.event__info {
  margin: 2rem 0;
  font: normal normal normal 0.9rem "Microsoft JhengHei";
}

.event__info .event__place {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.notice {
  color: #e74149;
  font: normal normal normal 1rem "Microsoft JhengHei";
}

.notice::before {
  content: "*";
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.questions {
  width: 100%;
}

.question {
  font: normal normal normal 1rem "Microsoft JhengHei";
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.question .question__title {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.question .question__title::after {
  content: "*";
  color: #e74149;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.question:nth-child(4) .type1 {
  margin-bottom: 23px;
}

.question:nth-child(6) .question__title::after {
  content: none;
}

.sub__title{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.question .answer {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.button__section {
  margin-top: 55px;
  font: normal normal normal 1rem "Microsoft JhengHei";
}

.submit__btn {
  background: #fad312;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.warning {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.copy__right {
  height: 30px;
  background: #000;
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-family: "Microsoft JhengHei";
}

.warning__style {
  color: #e74149;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
}

.warning__disappear {
  display: none;
}

.wrong__format {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Lazy-Form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <form class="apply__form">
      <h1 class="form__title">ABC FORM</h1>
      <div class="event__info">
        <p class="event__time">Event time</p>
        <p class="event__place">Event location</p>
      </div>
      <h3 class="notice">Must</h3>
      <div class="questions">
        <div class="question required">
          <p class="question__title">Nick name</p>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Answer" class="answer">
        </div>
        <div class="question required">
          <p class="question__title">Email</p>
          <input type="email" placeholder="Answer" class="answer">
        </div>
        <div class="question required">
          <p class="question__title">Phone</p>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Answer" class="answer" id="number">
        </div>
        <div class="question required">
          <p class="question__title">type</p>
          <div class="type1 radioType">
            <input type="radio" name="type" id="bed">
            <label for="bed">Bed</label>
          </div>
          <div class="type2 radioType">
            <input type="radio" name="type" id="phone">
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="question required">
          <p class="question__title">How do you know this?</p>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Answer" class="answer">
        </div>
        <div class="question">
          <p class="question__title">Other</p>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Answer" class="answer">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="button__section">
        <input type="submit" class="submit__btn" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two potential issues here. You are using querySelectorAll, which returns a static nodeList. But this shouldn't be the issue here, just something you need to be aware of.
You are using the some method in a wrong way.
You need to give it a function which checks each element and returns true or false.
If any of the element matches, the some method returns true as a whole.
So, it should look more like. (element down there is not correct, but I hope you get the idea.)

```
var response = reqChoiceArray.some(element => {
    if (!element.checked) {
      return false;
    }
    if (element.checked && element.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll('.warning__style').length) {
      return true;
    }
  })

if(!!response){
    element.parentElement.parentElement.lastChild.classList.add('warning__disappear');
}else{
    createWarning(element.parentElement.parentElement);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I didn't figure out why you say the static nodeList is a potential issue. So, the some method, I need to send a function. If there is a "ture' in the whole data, the result is ture, otherwise the result is false?

Comment: @Oscar In this case it isn't. You just need to be careful with it. If you change something on the node and uses the static nodelist, the change will not be in your static nodeList. If one of the elements returns true, the method returns true. If all are false, it returns false. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some